# Python requests http post data with cookies

Tags: python, cookies, http-post, python-requests

I have written an script in order to login to my account:

```
import requests
session=requests.Session()
post_data={'login':'login', 'username':'user', 'password':'password'}
cookies=session.cookies
post_response=session.post(url='https://www.mywebsite.com', cookies=cookies, data=post_data)
print post_response.content
```

When I run that the `web site` returns me an error:

**It seems your browser doesn't allow cookies, please enable cookies first.**

Comment: You don't need to pass `cookies` to the second request if you're using a session

Comment: Ok. When I don't use cookies it returns me the same error as well

Comment: My guess is that the website expects you to load a page (`GET`) before sending the `POST` request. Try loading the login form URL first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get('https://www.mywebsite.com/login.html')

post_data = {'login':'login', 'username':'user', 'password':'password'}
post_response = session.post(url='https://www.mywebsite.com', data=post_data)
print post_response.content
```